# Overriding a Constructor in an Extended Class (Decorator Pattern)

Tags: java, oop, decorator

Suppose I have a base abstract class `Base` that is extended by the classes `Base1`, `Base2`, and `Base 3`. It takes into its constructor an object containing information that I want to access in my decorator classes, `Decorator1` and `Decorator2`. The decorator classes extend `Decorator` which, in turn, extends `Base`.

```
InfoNeeded i = new InfoNeeded(user_input);
Base a = new Base1(i);
a = new Decorator1(a);
a = new Decorator2(a);
// etc...
```

My issue is that I need to access `i.getSomeValue1()`, `i.getSomeValue2()`, etc... within `Decorator1` and `Decorator2`. At first I tried putting a constructor to grab `i` in my abstract class `Base`. Then I implemented all of my `getSomeValue()` functions in there so I could just call `a.getSomeValue()` to pull the info I need. However, this caused issues because `Decorator` extends `Base`, forcing its constructor to take in `i` rather than `a`.

Is there a way to override the constructor in an extended class so that it's not forced to take in something I don't want?

Right now, I have my `getSomeValue()` functions copied and pasted among all of my base classes and decorator classes which works, but feels gross. I'd love to figure out a way to avoid this repetition. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, you cannot override a constructor. If the parent class needs something, you must make it available.

But, you can have more than one constructor, maybe this helps?

On the repetition of the `getSomeValue()` method, could you put it in the `Base` class so that all the others have it?